# Select from one of two views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to select from one of two views.
I would like my querying sql to be something like:

```
'select * from MyViewFunction(1);'
```

where the parameter 1 will deside from which view i should select.

So a function something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyViewFunction (@ViewId INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    IF(@ViewId == 1)
    BEGIN
            RETURN (SELECT * FROM  view1)
    END
        ELSE
    BEGIN
            RETURN (SELECT * FROM  view2 )
    END
```

Except that this does not work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: What happens? What results do you get? "Doesn't work" is a bit vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use **dynamic SQL**?

You will need a function and a procedure. Actually you can combine the function into the procedure but anyway -

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS
SELECT 1 AS [Test1]

CREATE VIEW view2
AS
SELECT 2 AS [Test2]

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ReturnViewName (@Id INTEGER) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
      CASE WHEN @Id = 1 THEN 'view1' WHEN @Id = 2 THEN 'view2' ELSE '' END
END


CREATE PROCEDURE MyViewProc (@ViewId INTEGER)  
AS

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Name AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Name = (SELECT dbo.fn_ReturnViewName(@ViewId))
SET @SQL = N'

            SELECT *
            FROM ' + @Name

            EXEC sp_executesql 
            @stmt = @SQL; 

EXEC MyViewProc @ViewID =1
EXEC MyViewProc @ViewID =2
```

Comment: Can't get this working, no matter how I try to change it.
I tried:
        RETURN  SELECT * FROM (Select dbo.fn_ReturnViewName(1))
and:
RETURN
        SELECT * FROM (Select dbo.fn_ReturnViewName(1))

None of this works

Answer (score 2):

That is declaring an inline table valued function , that, by definition, can only contain a single SELECT statement.

If you have to do this,  then you need a multi statement table value function, be aware though that this does not seem like something i would want to see in a production enviroment and you need to step back a bit to a 'proper' solution...  Though what that looks like there is not enough info to say.

This [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/discussionofsqlserver/2012/02/15/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/) will give more details on the operational differences of the two.